# trouble with loading javascript in visual studio 2012

Tags: vb.net

Hey How would I load this code

http://jsfiddle.net/xw89p/

in a simple web form in visual studio.

For example can I insert this into the

```
  var rotation = function (){
  $("#image").rotate({
  angle:0, 
  animateTo:360, 
  callback:enter code here rotation,
  easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value,
    c: change In value, d: duration
      return c*(t/d)+b;
  }
 });
    }
    rotation();​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that code in a JavaScript file (.js), then in your web form file, add a  tag that references the .js file:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

A second possibility is to put that code inside the script tag in your web form file:

```
<script>
var rotation = function (){
   $("#image").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
   });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    rotation();​
});
</script>
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure to first reference jQuery and whatever other javascript libraries you need BEFORE inclusing your js file, or BEFORE the inline script tag.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Here's a working verison on my side:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">​
    <script  type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rotation() {
        $("#image").rotate({
            angle: 0,
            animateTo: 360,
            callback: rotation,
            easing: function(x, t, b, c, d) { // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
                return c * (t / d) + b;
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        rotation();
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting... Assuming no additional files - I tried pasting into a form and all I see is a Google image, no rotation. I am not a web developer, so just curious if [I did something wrong](http://pastebin.com/0zwUnpmH).

Comment: you forgot the opening <script> tag before line 7

Comment: Ok, try exactly how I wrote it, especially the $(document).ready part

Comment: plus i tried the above and getting the same problem as Neolisk

Comment: First of all, make sure that when you look at the source (right-click/view source in your browser windows) that you can see the jquery and other libraries being referenced.